# How do I stop selenium automation if 20% or 1st 20 test cases test methods are failed?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have 100 test cases, if 20% or first 20 test cases all fail how can I stop the execution ?
Already have testng ITestResult where should I break the build?

```
@Test(retryAnalyzer = ReTryFail.class, dataProvider = "SanityTCTest", dataProviderClass = utility.Xlsdataprovider.class, groups = "Dashboard", alwaysRun = true)
public void Sanity_TC001(LinkedHashMap<String, String> data) throws InterruptedException, SQLException {

 Some code 
}

@Test(retryAnalyzer = ReTryFail.class, dataProvider = "SanityTCTest", dataProviderClass = utility.Xlsdataprovider.class, groups = "Dashboard", alwaysRun = true)
public void Sanity_TC002(LinkedHashMap<String, String> data) throws InterruptedException, SQLException {

 Some code 
}

@Test(retryAnalyzer = ReTryFail.class, dataProvider = "SanityTCTest", dataProviderClass = utility.Xlsdataprovider.class, groups = "Dashboard", alwaysRun = true)
public void Sanity_TC003(LinkedHashMap<String, String> data) throws InterruptedException, SQLException {

 Some code 
}
///////////////////////////////
```

Where can I break this suite if Result, "FAIL is over 20 ? 
DO i require to create new class or can I add in same below?

```
@AfterMethod(alwaysRun = true)
public void reporterDataResults(ITestResult Result) throws InterruptedException {
    boolean flag = false;
    Testfail = TestResultStatus.Testfail;

    /*System.out.println("test fail flag in AfterMethod: " + Testfail); */
    if (Result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
        Resmark.put(Result.getName(), "");
        captureScreenShot(Result, "SKIP", getDriver());
        Reporter.log(Result.getName() + " is SKIPPED");
        Add_Log.info(Result.getName() + " is SKIPPED");
        TestResultTL.put(Result.getName(), "SKIP");
        if (!(getDriver() == null)) {
            closeWebBrowser();
        }
    } else if (Result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {

        Collection<String> values = TestResultStatus.mpaskeysnew.get(Result.getName());
        String resultout = String.join(" | ", values);
        System.out.println(resultout);
        Resmark.put(Result.getName(), resultout);

        captureScreenShot(Result, "FAIL", getDriver());
        Reporter.log(Result.getName() + " is FAIL");
        Add_Log.info(Result.getName() + " is FAIL");
        if (!(getDriver() == null)) {
            closeWebBrowser();
        }
        TestResultTL.put(Result.getName(), "FAIL");


    } else {
        captureScreenShot(Result, "PASS", getDriver());
        Resmark.put(Result.getName(), "");
        Reporter.log(Result.getName() + " is PASS");
        Add_Log.info(Result.getName() + " is PASS");
        if (!(getDriver() == null)) {
            closeWebBrowser();
        }
        TestResultTL.put(Result.getName(), "PASS");

    }
    Testskip = false;
    TestResultStatus.Testfail = false;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement [`ISuiteListener`](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners) and in `onFinish` method you'll have access to  `ISuite` and  [`ISuiteResult`](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/org/testng/ISuiteResult.html)

Then you can do

```
public void onFinish(ISuite suite) {

        final Map<java.lang.String,ISuiteResult>  res = suite.getResults();

                for (ISuiteResult r : res.values()) {
                  context =  r.getTestContext()  ;
                  failedTestCases =context.getFailedTests().size();
                 }
         }
```

`size()` will give you number of failed test for that suite. Once you know that number you can implement to stop execution using strategies in [this](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12937/how-to-stop-running-selenium-tests-after-webdriver-quit)

If your test cases are in different suites then in each call to `onFinish` method you can count number of failed test cases per suite and based on that stop execution.

One other alternative is to implement [`ITestListener`](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/org/testng/ITestListener.html) . In `onTestFailure` method you have access to [`ITestResult`](https://javadoc.jitpack.io/com/github/cbeust/testng/master/javadoc/org/testng/ITestListener.html#onTestFailure-org.testng.ITestResult-)

You can count how many times `onTestFailure` method is called and based on that stop execution. I think implementing `ITestListener` is more suitable and easy in your case.

Here , I edited to explain how you'd implement listener

```
import org.testng.ISuiteListener;

public class listener implements Itestlistener {
            public int i = 0;

             public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {

                     result.getName();
                     i++;
                     //your break logic goes here
                       if (i ==20){
                              // do something or call some function to stop execution
                             }
         }

     }
```

You can read more about testng listeners [here](https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners) .

For your **EDIT** above (if you want to go that way). Though  I still think you should implement listener, which is more cleaner. It will be called only when the test fails.

But   do the same thing as I did in  `onTestFailure` method , add a counter and increase it in `else if` .

```
   public int i = 0;  //do this in your class
```

then in your method

```
 else if (Result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
    i++;  //increase counter here
    Collection<String> values = TestResultStatus.mpaskeysnew.get(Result.getName());
    String resultout = String.join(" | ", values);
    System.out.println(resultout);
    Resmark.put(Result.getName(), resultout);

    captureScreenShot(Result, "FAIL", getDriver());
    Reporter.log(Result.getName() + " is FAIL");
    Add_Log.info(Result.getName() + " is FAIL");
    if (!(getDriver() == null)) {
        closeWebBrowser();
    }
       TestResultTL.put(Result.getName(), "FAIL");
      if (i==20){
         // stop execution here
      }

  }
```

Comment: I have update my question added After method where should I break the if over 20 ?